# Where is the eclipse web browser's "back" button?

Tags: eclipse

Just reading a web page inside of eclipse. Alt-Left takes me to the previous piece of code I was editing. Where is the "back" button for going to the previous web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on a context menu. Right click the page and select 'back.'